# MVC3 Dynamic DataAnnotation attribute StringLength

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

**UPDATE #3: Entire question**

I have a class HB:

```
    public class HB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3000)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }

}
```

And Title:

```
    public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MaxChar { get; set; }   
}
```

Before you can write a HB (which is kind of an article), you have to choose your title, so your StringLength for HB.Text can be determined. Meaning, this article can only have a certain amount of chars, deppending on what 'Title' the writer has. Example: Title1 can only write a 'HB' with 1000 chars, and Title2 can write a 'HB' with 3000 chars. So. Thats means the the `StringLength` has to come from `Title.MaxChar`. Whats the smartest way to do that?

The Title entity is prefixed data that will be stored in the db.

To be crystal clear, what I want to achieve is something in the line with: `[StringLength(Title.MaxChar)]`

Ive done structure/design for this mechanism in Webforms a million times, my brain just cant addapt to mvc, so some help would be appreciated. Code would be even more appreciated.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: @jeremy, `[StringLength(set_by_view)]`

Comment: No that's how you're trying to do something.  What is your intended purpose here?  Why are you trying to dynamically change the string length of a property?  I think you are probably trying to do something for which a mechanism already exists.

Comment: @Jeremy - Sorry for the late answer guys, been real busy. Ive updated the whole question, so if you could take a look at it again, that would be sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that is not possible as written.  This strikes me as trying to force business logic into the model that belongs in the controller.

In this situation, I would make the attribute on the Text property `[StringLength(3000)]`.  In the controller, during validation, I would write something along these lines:

```
public ActionResult (HB model)
{
    if (model.Text.Length > model.Title.MaxChar){
        ModelState.AddModelError("Text", string.Format("Text for this Title cannot exceed {0} characters.", model.Title.MaxChar));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //do stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); //or something
    } 
    else 
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I believe this will accomplish what you are trying to do.  Now, for the Title object, I'd flatten that out a bit in your model:

```
public class HB
{
    #region Base Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3000)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Title Properties

    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
    public int TitleMaxChar { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

This is assuming you need to display that information in your view.  If you just need to reference it for your business logic validation, just have the `TitleId` property and use that to instantiate the `Title` object in your controller when you need it.  Don't forget to make hidden inputs for each of these properties if they are not editable!

Comment: BTW, noticed that I put a bug in the code; just fixed it.  Also, you might have problems with the Title object in your model.  Complex objects can be a pain to pass around through the model.  Consider only referencing an ID to the Title, and fetching the information from your data store as needed.

Comment: Yeah i noticed. No problem. But yes the Title object. Null reference :S. Ive updated the question with the way ive done in, but hb.Title.MaxChar is null in the if statement. Please take a look :)

Comment: Cool. But the flattening out thing wont work. I need the Title class as its own entity, as they are prefixed data that will be stored in the db, and I will need CRUD functions on em. I will like the app to work this way: Before you can write a HB (article), you have to choose your title, so your HB.Text has a certain MaxLength.

Comment: Never mind Jeremy. Your solution combined with my stuff works. I just forgot the HidenFor => model.Title as you might have mentioned. So thanks alot for your time. I have other issues now, but I think I can handle that my self :)

Comment: Nope, I couldnt handle it. Now it creates a new Title record every time a create a new HB. Check out [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403261/issue-with-entity-framwork-db-relations thanks